# biblatex: extract authors seperately

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Given and BibTeX entry

```
@articel{paper,
  author={Jane Doe and John Hansen and Tom Nielsen},
  year={2012},
  title={Paper title}
}
```

How do I make commands (using `biblatex`) that

1. insert "Jane Doe, John Hansen and Tom Nielsen" in the text (`\citeauthor` only use the last names)
2. insert "Jane Doe" into the text (i.e. only the first author)

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the definitions for (simplified) citation commands to print the (full) name of the first author and the full names of the authors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@articel{test,
  author={Jane Doe and John Hansen and Tom Nielsen},
  year={2012},
  title={Paper title}
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=6]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{onlyfirst}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citefirstauthor}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[onlyfirst][1-1]{labelname}
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenames}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[first-last]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
First author only: \citefirstauthor{test}

All authors: \citenames{test}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shame there isn't an MWE with this post; I just tried this code with TexLive 2014 - and still get first name initals only; please see the [below post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207529/2595)... any help?

Comment: @sdaau included full MWE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MWE based on [@Guido](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200119/2595)'s answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{btest.bib}
@BOOK{Author2014,
  author = {Jane Doe and John Hansen and Tom Nielsen},
  publisher = {Another},
  title = {The Author book},
  year = 2014
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[%
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true,
  doi=false,
  url=true,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{btest}

\DeclareNameFormat{onlyfirst}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citefirstauthor}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[onlyfirst][1-1]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenames}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[first-last]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

Testing citenames here: \citenames{Author2014}

\end{document}
```

Compiled this with `pdflatex test.tex`, `biber test`, `pdflatex test.tex`, `pdflatex test.tex`, and still I get this:

[image: test.png]

I use the exactly the same code as in the answer, yet I get the first names as initial only. Why and how could I get the full names?

EDIT: just found that one just needs to add `firstinits=false` to the package loading:

```
...
\usepackage[%
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true,
  doi=false,
  url=true,
  firstinits=false, %% this!
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{btest}
...
```

... and then full names are generated:

[image: test2.png]

EDIT2: ... and if you need this command to switch explicitly in an environment like IEEE where firstinits=true, and you don't want to set `firstinits=false` in preamble - probably this will work:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenames}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {%
    % \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=false} % only in preamble
    \makeatletter%
    \setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{firstinits=false}%
    \makeatother%
    \printnames[first-last]{labelname}%
    \makeatletter%
    \setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{firstinits=true}%
    \makeatother%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: The solution I gave does not use `style=ieee`, it works with  `style=authoryear`.

Comment: @Guido - it turns out in my case `firstinits=false,` fixed things. Cheers!